# Firebase idTokens

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

When i deployed my app to AWS and used the same google id for login, the custom claims were not present on the idtoken. Then i checked the tokens when running the app on localhost and logged in with the same google acount from the same machine.
The idtoken were different. Are firebase tokens generated every time a user signs in from a different browser window (as in my case, one browser tab logged into localhost version of the app and another logged into the AWS version) and/or a different machine/location.
Do we have follow the same procedure of reverifying the idtoken on server and attach custom claims everytime a user logs in?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get new custom claims to show up in a Firebase Auth ID token is to get a new token completely.  You can refresh the on you have, or simply sign out and back in again.  There are no workarounds for this.

Comment: thanks Doug! The user was not a new user, custom claims already existed The login via AWS had the correct custom claims. However, when using the same login account from localhost, the custom claims were missing.